# Python: duplicate one row into two rows and make changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this pandas dataframe with two columns and the index is shown too.

```
    Name    Membership       Specs
0   Adam    NORMAL           170
1   James   NORMAL           170
2   Michael ADMINCOORDINATOR 170
3   Lina    NORMAL           170
4   Alexey  ADMINCOORDINATOR 170
5   David   NORMAL           170
```

I would like to duplicate the **ADMINCOORDINATOR** rows and then change the values to following format:-

```
    Name    Membership  Specs
0   Adam    NORMAL      170
1   James   NORMAL      170
2   Michael ADMIN       160
3   Michael COORDINATOR 180
4   Lina    NORMAL      170
5   Alexey  ADMIN       160
6   Alexey  COORDINATOR 180
7   David   NORMAL      170
```

so the idea is to split ADMINCOORDINATOR into two rows and change the values ADMIN = 160, Coordinator = 180. Moreover, I would like to keep the sorting for data.

Thank you

Comment: Are those values presenting -10/+10 factors of the initial value?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
dmap = {'ADMIN': 160, 'COORDINATOR': 180}
update_specs = lambda x: x['Membership'].map(dmap).fillna(x['Specs']).astype(int)

out = (df.assign(Membership=df['Membership'].str.findall(r'ADMIN|COORDINATOR|.+'))
         .explode('Membership', ignore_index=True)
         .assign(Specs=update_specs))
print(out)

# Output
      Name   Membership  Specs
0     Adam       NORMAL    170
1    James       NORMAL    170
2  Michael        ADMIN    160
3  Michael  COORDINATOR    180
4     Lina       NORMAL    170
5   Alexey        ADMIN    160
6   Alexey  COORDINATOR    180
7    David       NORMAL    170
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that, The NORMAL specs can be anything. it might be 140 or another value. using the above code, the NORMAL specs will be 170 for all rows

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
df = df.assign(Membership=df['Membership'].str.findall(r'ADMIN|COORDINATOR|.+'))
    df = df.explode('Membership')
    def Membership(df):
        if df['Membership'] == "ADMIN":
            return "160"
        if df['Membership'] == "COORDINATOR":
            return "180"
        else:
            return df['Specs']
    
    df['Specs_new'] = df.apply(Membership, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With artificial splitting on `ADMINCOORDINATOR` keyword and exploding on `Membership`:

```
df.Membership = df.Membership.str.replace(r'(ADMIN)', r'\1,').str.split(',')
df = df.explode('Membership')
df.Specs = np.where(df.Membership.eq('ADMIN'), 160, 
                    np.where(df.Membership.eq('COORDINATOR'), 180, df.Specs))
```

---

```
      Name   Membership  Specs
0     Adam       NORMAL    170
1    James       NORMAL    170
2  Michael        ADMIN    160
2  Michael  COORDINATOR    180
3     Lina       NORMAL    170
4   Alexey        ADMIN    160
4   Alexey  COORDINATOR    180
5    David       NORMAL    170
```